# githup AOTH client app

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I read the post from Caroline church on https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc. this uses githup AOTH for the rest server. I would like to know if these is possible to perform authenticating in the client app automatically. I mean, it it authenticated when adding a participant without the they knowing about it?

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorization-options-for-oauth-apps/

Once you've authenticated your client app to (say) Github (in this example), it can use the token to make authenticated requests. Your application user (someone with authority to add a business network participant) would use its business network card, to interact with the business network and create participants - but the destination end-user (for whom an existing blockchain identity and participant may be linked) doesn't have to know, no.